# Calcular diferença entre campo timestamp com timestamp específico

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando desenvolver uma tabela de ranking para uma espécie de questionário.

Cada dia é feita uma pergunta as 16h, que pode ser respondida até as 17:59:59 do dia seguinte. 
A tabela tem que mostrar a posição dos participantes tendo em conta o numero de respostas certas e o tempo.

Ou seja que responde certo e mais rápido fica em primeiro.
O numero de perguntas respondidas também conta, se arque não responde um dia é penalizado.

A minha tabela será do género:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+
|userid | acertou |      timestamp      |
+-------+---------+---------------------+
|   2   |    1    | 2018-02-07 16:00:01 |
|   1   |    1    | 2018-02-07 16:02:00 |
|   3   |    1    | 2018-02-07 17:00:00 |
|   1   |    0    | 2018-02-08 16:00:02 |
|   3   |    1    | 2018-02-08 16:00:05 |
|   2   |    0    | 2018-02-08 16:01:00 |
+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

Para já comecei com este query:

```
SELECT `userid`, `acertou`, `timestamp`, 
count(acertou) as cont 
FROM `resultados` 
WHERE acertou = 1
GROUP BY `userid `
ORDER BY cont DESC, timestamp DESC
```

Mas já percebi que isto não é o que pretendo porque o ranking tem que ser acumulativo mas tendo em conta os vários dias.

Alguém tem ideia como posso fazer isto?

Comment: faz um SUM na pontuação e um calculo de media pela diferença de time stamp.

Comment: Calcula a 'nota' da pessoa em mais uma coluna e faz um SUM() por usuário. Sugiro fazer uma funcion que receba o acerto e a data-hora e calcule a nota, desse jeito fica mais fácil caso precise mudar a regra ou o horário.

Comment: mas eu nao tenho pontuação, só tenho pergunta certa ou errada

Comment: Você quer saber quem acertou mais e em menos tempo é isso ?

Comment: certo, tendo em conta que é uma pergunta por dia.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme no chat, o seu problema é que não tem uma referência com a data inicial das perguntas, então não tem como calcular a diferença entre as datas.

Tendo essa tabela com as datas e perguntas, o select seria basicamente dessa forma:

```
-- soma acertos, e verifica a diferença em horas, minutos, segundos
SELECT userid, SUM(acertou),
-- Diferença em horas
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,timestamp,CAST(CONCAT_WS(' ',date(timestamp), '17:59:59') as DATETIME))) horas,
-- Diferença em minutos
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timestamp,CAST(CONCAT_WS(' ',date(timestamp), '17:59:59') as DATETIME))) minutos,
-- Diferença em segundos
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,timestamp,CAST(CONCAT_WS(' ',date(timestamp), '17:59:59') as DATETIME))) segundos
FROM resultados
-- agrupa por usuário
GROUP BY userid
-- OPICIONAL, verifica se o usuário respondeu todas as perguntas
HAVING SUM(acert) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(perg_n) FROM resultados) qtd_perguntas)
-- ordena pelo que tem mais acertos, depois pelos tempos ( quanto mais tempo sobrou, menos tempo usou.
ORDER BY acertos DESC, horas DESC, minutos DESC, segundos DESC;
```

Comment: so que o resultado nao he so pelas respostas certas e sim por quem demorou menos para responder tbm. tem q falzer uma media dos segundos que ele demorou para responder de cada dia.

Comment: Então é "respostas certas pelo tempo"...

Comment: fui testar mas deu o seguinte erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') tempo FROM resultados GROUP BY userid ORDER BY acertou DESC, tempo' at line 2

Comment: Faltou um `)`. Corrigido !

Comment: mesmo assim da erro, não percebo
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) tempo FROM resultados GROUP BY userid ORDER BY acertou DESC, tempo' at line 2

Comment: Acertei tente novamente.

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado pela ajuda, ja não dá erro no entanto os resultados não são o que estou a procura.
Repare que existe uma pergunta cada dia, não é não so conta a rapidez da resposta mas quem respondeu a todos os dias certo.

Comment: Então ainda não entendi como você quer que exiba o resultado. Você precisa explicar melhor, por exemplo: Preciso filtrar todos os que acertaram TODOS OS DIAS, e ver quem respondeu mais rápido. Só nesse exemplo já muda o `WHERE = 1`, porque ele só irá filtrar as respostas certas mas não sabe quantas são no total. Entre outros fatores. Precisa explicar detalhadamente para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: @RBZ editei a pergunta explicando melhor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72915/discussion-between-rbz-and-helderk).